# How to disable Taskbar always on Top in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, taskbar

Whenever I launch VLC or web page or word document, the windows 7 taskbar is always on top. 
I have been looking for this option in Windows 7 ( the option to let me disable the Taskbar on Top, not autohide).

Thank you.

Comment: Have you considered enabling the auto-hide taskbar feature?

Answer (score 1):

I absolutely empathize. I DESPISE Microsoft's imbecilic tyranny over my taskbar, forcing me to perpetually waste a huge column of space on my desktop. Up until winXP, there was a checkbox for this, but then they decided that they know better than I how I want my desktop to behave. Idiots.

Rant aside, Taskbar Tweaker will let you relegate the damn taskbar to the background where it belongs: http://rammichael.com/7-taskbar-tweaker
In version 5.3, set "disable topmost" to 1 or 2 in the advanced options. (See help file.)

Comment: Can you expand on how this application works? Maybe include some screenshots?

Comment: @Burgi To access the "advanced options" window, [click on the "7TT" icon in the top left and select "Advanced Options"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1YIWi.png), then you can [set "disable topmost" from 0, to 1 or 2 in that window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n51ud.png), option 2 is probably what you want. Note that I customized other things with this utility, only that one setting in "Advanced settings" matters, the rest of your settings don't have to match mine.